# How to fork a ffmpeg stream in order to read it with ffplay?

Tags: pipe, ffmpeg, file-descriptors, streaming

Say I create an encrypted webcam capture

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i plughw:0,0 \
-f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video0 \
-f ogg >(openssl enc -k $PASSWORD -aes-256-cbc -out webcam.aes-256-cbc
```

**How can I fork this stream in order to read it with `ffplay` using the stream directly (and not by encrypting the generated file obviously)?**

---

**First guess**: find the file descriptor of the `ffmpeg` process

Comment: Second guess: Use `ffmpeg ... | tee >(openssl ...) | ffplay ...`. Though I assume interesting things will happen if both destinations read at different speeds ...

Comment: No. The idea is to have the encrypted capture to be running in the background and to read this stream without stopping it. I don't want to stop the capture to restart a capture with `ffplay`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what exactly are you trying to do. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The question may not be properly  asked: New one: [How to read a webcam that is already used by a background capture?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343832/how-to-read-a-webcam-that-is-already-used-by-a-background-capture). I think I'll end up using fifo.