# How to read a webcam that is already used by a background capture?

Tags: pipe, ffmpeg, file-descriptors, fifo

A `ffmpeg` webcam capture is running in the background.

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video0  capture.mp4    (1)
```

I am therefore unable to read it with `ffplay` since the device `/dev/video0` is used:

```
ffplay -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video0                  (2)
[...]
/dev/video0: Device or resource busy
```

**How to read the webcam with `ffplay` without stopping the background capture?**

PS: The background capture command should not be modified. I am aware that this can be done by modifying the command (1) with fifo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do this:

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1
```

If you get similar error like `modprobe: FATAL: Module v4l2loopback not found in directory /lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-amd64`, just install v4l2loopback-dkms first, e.g.:

```
sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms
```

Now run it first (Note that it can't run as background process by trailing `&`):

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2  -i /dev/video0 -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video1
```

Without stop the process above, in other bash session(s), you should able to run your two commands, i.e. `ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video1  capture.mp4` and `ffplay -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video1` (change it to /dev/video1) at the same time..

If you set it to `2`:

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=2
```

Then you can do `ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video1  -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video2`, which allow you to used both /dev/video1 and /dev/video2 in the same time.